# mocking a socket connection in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to write unit tests for a class in python. The class opens a tcp socket on **init**. I am trying to mock this out so that I can assert that connecting is called with the correct values but obviously doesn't actually happen in unit tests. I have tired MagicMock, patch, etc but I have not found a solution.

My class so far looks like this

```
import socket

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tcp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.tcp_socket.connect('0.0.0.0', '6767')
```

Comment: why not just actually connect?

Comment: @JoranBeasley because it may lead to stalled builds if the connection takes too long to establish. That is the reason we need mocks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you just want to assert that `connect` is called correctly, it's a simple as

```
import mock
import socket

class MyClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.tcp_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.tcp_socket.connect('0.0.0.0', '6767')

with mock.patch('socket.socket'):
    c = MyClass()
    c.tcp_socket.connect.assert_called_with('0.0.0.0', '6767')
```

If you have to import a module first to access `MyClass`, you'll need to adjust the patch slightly:

```
from mymodule import MyClass
import mock

with mock.patch('mymodule.socket.socket'):
    c = MyClass()
    c.tcp_socket.connect.assert_called_with('0.0.0.0', '6767')
```

Comment: In Python 3.3+, you can simply `import unittest.mock` as `mock` is now included in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html