# How to do assert on instantiated mock class object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-mock

In the constructor of my class under test a socket object is instantiated and assigned to a class member. I mocked the socket class and set a mocked socket object as return value to the socket constructor call. I then want to assert that connect() and sendall() is called on that object. I always get the assert error that the functions are not called when I assert on the original mocked class object or the one that I set to return on constructor call.

I know I can’t mock the class that is under test (and its members) because that would defeat the purpose here.

Pseudo code:

```
import socket

Class socketHandler():
    def __init__(...):
    self.mySocket = socket(...)
    ...
    self.mySocket.connect(...)

    def write(message):
        self.mySocket.sendall(message)
```

Test:

```
from unittest import mock
from unittest.mock import MagicMock #not sure if i need this
import pytest
import socketHandler

@mock.patch(socketHandler.socket)
def test_socket_handler(mockSocket):
    ...
    new_sock = mock_socket()
    mock_socket.return_value = new_sock

    mySocketHandler = SocketHandler(...)

    mock_socket.socket.assert_called_with(...)
    new_sock.connect.assert_called_with(...) #fails (never called)
    mock_socket.connect.assert_called_with(...) #fails (never called)
    #likewise for the sendall() method call when mysocketHandler.write(..)
    #is called
```

The purpose of this test is:

1. ensure the constructor of socket library is called with the right arguments.
2. ensure that connect() is called with right arguments.
3. ensure that sendall() is called with exactly what I want it to be called, when I pass message into mySocketHandler.write() method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete answer derived from hints given by @ryanh119 and this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31864168/mocking-a-socket-connection-in-python)

I will fix the example given above by ryanh119 and refrain from editing original question which i messed up, so for completeness:

```
from unittest import mock
import pytest
import socketHandler

@mock.patch("app_directory.socketHandler.socket")
def test_socket_handler(mockSocketClass):

# mockSocketClass is already a mock, so we can call production right away.
mySocketHandler = SocketHandler(...)

# Constructor of mockSocketClass was called, since the class was imported
#like: import socket we need to:
mockSocketClass.socket.assert_called_with(...)

# Production called connect on the class instance variable
# which is a mock so we can check it directly.
# so lets just access the instance variable sock
mySocketHandler.mySocket.connect.assert_called_with(...)

# The same goes for the sendall call:
mySocketHandler.mySocket.sendall.assert_called_with(expectedMessage)
```

I also did some research and there would have been two more solutions that I want to mention. They are not as pythonicaly correct like the above ones but here it is:

1. Make use of dependency injection by changing the `__init__` of socketHandler to take in a socket object and only instantiate it if not supplied in the args. That way i could have passed in a mock or MagicMock object and used that to do the asserts on.
2. Make use of a extremely powerful mocking/patching tool called [MonkeyPatch](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) which actually can patch/mock instance variables of classes. This approach would have been like trying to kill a fly with a rocket launcher.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track, but there are a couple things that need to change for this test to work.

Part of your problem right off the bat is that the mock that `patch` passes into your test method is called `mockSocket`, but your test code is referring to something called `mock_socket`.

Also, `patch`'s first argument, the thing you want to patch, should be a *string representation* of the path to the module where you want to patch something. If your file structure looks like this:

```
|-- root_directory
|   |
|   |-- app_directory
|   |   |-- socketHandler.py
|   |   `-- somethingElse.py
|   |
|   `-- test_directory
|       |-- testSocketHandler.py
|       `-- testSomethingElse.py
```

and you run your tests from the root directory, you'd want to call patch like this: `@mock.patch("app_directory.socketHandler.socket")`

1. Constructor is called - The most important thing to realize is that `mockSocket` is a `Mock` object representing the socket *class*. So to test that the constructor was called, you need to check `mockSocket.assert_called_with(...)`. That will pass if your production calls `socket(...)`.

   You may also want to assert that `mySocketHandler.socket` is the same object as `mockSocket.return_value`, to test that mySocketHandler not only calls the constructor, but assigns it to the right attribute.
2. and 3. `connect` and `sendall` are called properly - You should never call your mock in a test, because it can lead to falsely-passing assertions. In other words, you want your production code to be the only thing calling mocks. This means you shouldn't use the line `new_sock = mock_socket()`, because then your previous assertion about the constructor will pass no matter what your production code does, and I think it's causing your other assertions to fail.

   `mockSocket`is already an instance of `Mock`, so it's return value will automatically be another, different `Mock` instance. Therefore, you don't need the first 2 lines of your test code above, and you only need one of the assertions on `connect`. The same ideas apply to `sendall`.

That's a lot to take in, here's what your test would look like if I wrote it:

```
from unittest import mock, TestCase
import pytest
import socketHandler

class TestSocketHandler(TestCase):
    @mock.patch("app_directory.socketHandler.socket")
    def test_socket_handler(mockSocketClass): # renamed this variable to clarify that it's a mock of a class.

        # mockSocketClass is already a mock, so we can call production right away.
        mySocketHandler = SocketHandler(...)

        # Constructor of mockSocketClass was called
        mockSocketClass.assert_called_with(...)

        # Instance of mockSocketClass was assigned to correct attribute on SocketHandler
        self.assertIs(mockSocketClass.return_value, mySocketHandler.socket)

        # Production called connect on the return_value of the mock module, i.e. the instance of socket.
        mockSocketClass.return_value.connect.assert_called_with(...)

        # If SocketHandler's constructor calls sendall:
        mockSocketClass.return_value.sendall.assert_called_with(expectedMessage)
```

Bonus Round! `MagicMock`s behave like `Mock`s, except that they implement some default values for [some magic methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html?highlight=magicmock#unittest.mock.MagicMock). I don't use them unless I absolutely need them. Here's an example:

```
from mock import Mock, MagicMock

mock = Mock()
magic_mock = MagicMock()

int(mock)
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Mock'

len(mock)
>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'Mock' has no len()

int(magic_mock)
>>> 1

len(magic_mock)
>>> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was not entirely correct but it helped me in finding the right answer. Sorry for my syntax mistakes, however:

Comment: 1. You defined a method so you cant use references to self, assertIs is a method from the unittest.TestCase class!
2. mockSocketClass.return_value.connect.assert_called_with(...) was never called when I tried your code. 

Why not use MagicMock? Their autospec or spec ability make them very useful.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you were using unittest.TestCase and had omitted it from your code.

You can use spec with `Mock` as well. I avoid them because I rarely need any magic methods defined for me, and I don't want my tests to pass when they shouldn't because I forgot to override a magic method on a `MagicMock`