# Force sock.accept() to raise exception for tests

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, python-asyncio

As part of a suite of tests, I would like server_sock.accept() to raise an exception (that isn't BlockingIOError)

```
server_sock = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM, proto=IPPROTO_TCP)
server_sock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
server_sock.setblocking(False)
server_sock.bind(('', 8080))
server_sock.listen(IPPROTO_TCP)

# Would like to raise an exception
server_sock.accept()
```

I am aware I can patch the object in some way to force it, but I would like to simulate as close to a real situation as possible, so the exception to be raised by actual network/OS conditions, e.g. by some behaviour on a remote socket. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You should be forcing it via a mocked socket. If you search for that you may find example code.  Or you'll want to know what exceptions socket throws. You can find the python and C code on github.

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/socket.py

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/socketmodule.c

If you want to go deeper look at the accept man page to see what errors it returns.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html

A possibly linux specific error:

> In addition, Linux accept() may fail if:
>
> ```
>   EPERM  Firewall rules forbid connection.
> ```

Comment: I agree.  You know the exceptions socket throws so just mock them. This answer has some basics on mocking a socket. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31864324/9638646